# Spark Not Picking All Data from Kafka within Microbatch Duration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark cluster and a Kafka cluster. Spark is getting data from a topic "one", processing it, and sending it to another topic called "two" on the same Kafka cluster. I am using kafka-console-producer.sh to write data in topic "one" and kafka-console-consumer.sh to read data from topic "two".

Here is my Spark code:

```
# Read data from topic "one" and write it as it is in topic "two"
import sys
import os

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

from kafka import KafkaProducer

input_zookeeper = "192.168.106.214:2181,192.168.106.213:2181"
output_zookeeper = "192.168.106.214:9092,192.168.106.213:9092"
input_topic = "one"
output_topic = "two"

def process_results(data_to_process, producer, output_topic):
    try:
        if(data_to_process):
            producer.send(output_topic, str(data_to_process))
    except Exception as e:
        print ("exception: ")
        print (e)
        print("[warning] Unable to send data through topic " + output_topic)

sc = SparkContext(appName="test4")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

input_stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, input_zookeeper, "spark-consumer-test4", {input_topic: 2})

kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=output_zookeeper, client_id="spark-producer-test4")
input_stream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: process_results(rdd.collectAsMap(), kafka_producer, output_topic))
try:
    kafka_producer.flush()
except Exception as e:
    print("[warning] unable to assess producer")

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The Kafka cluster consists of two nodes: 192.168.106.213, 192.168.106.214.
The topics "one" and "two" have two partitions each.

**Now when I write several inputs on the producer (console), not everything is processed by Spark**. I suspect that it has to do something with the microbatch duration. If the microbatch duration is 5 sec, and I input multiple different inputs in the producer console within 5 seconds, only one or two of them get printed on the consumer console of topic "two". If I enter inputs at an interval of 5 seconds each, every one of them gets printed. How do I resolve this so that every line coming in from Kafka is processed?

I also tried giving input to Kafka on topic "one" by other ways and the result was still the same.

Please let me know if any more code/output is required.

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether you have given the duration correctly because i could see the duration as 1 in the code.Below is the code line

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
```

Also just give a double check whether you have to give duration as 5000 or 5 ,sometimes it can be in milliseconds.

Comment: If the microbatch duration is 5 sec, and I input multiple different inputs in the producer console within 5 seconds, only one or two of them get printed on the consumer console of topic "two". If I enter inputs at an interval of 5 seconds each, every one of them gets printed. 
The problem is not with the time duration but with the way spark behaves within the microbatch duration. It should process all data which came in but it only processes some.